# How to merge two apps in facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have create a two apps in facebook. 
one for my mobile site.
second for my mobile app.
These both have different facebook app ids and people logged in both of them.
Now how to merge these with out losing any statistics/ logins ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can´t just merge them, you can only remove one of them. I guess it´s no big deal for the statistics (you can export them), but you will definitely have to let the Users of the old App know that they have to authorize the App again (the new one). Be careful with the App Scoped IDs too, the Users will most likely get a new ID - except both Apps are v1.0 Apps and all Users switch to the new App before end of April 2015...Maybe you could keep the old App alive during the transfer and use the Business Mapping API to match IDs between the Apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business